# filtrar datos en datagridview c# window form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas quisiera que me ayuden estoy tratando de realizar como un buscador en mi Texbox.
 Les explico. lo que quiero que en mi texbox escribir mi primer apellido y en el datagridview Salga todos los que empiezen con ese apellido.

Error me genera en :

dtListar_Alumno.Rows.Clear();

por ejemplo en la imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no me esta logrando salir en mi codebing me sale un error, estoy realizando en 3 capas.

este es mi Procedimiento

```
create procedure Buscar_Alumno
@apellidopaterno varchar(260)
as
SELECT IDAlumno, Alu_apepaterno +' '+alu_apematerno AS 'Apellidos',alu_nombres AS 'Nombres' FROM alumno where Alu_apepaterno=@apellidopaterno
```

Mi capa Datos:

```
  public static DataTable Buscar_Alumno(Cls_E_Alumno objE)
        {
            return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(conexion, "Buscar_Alumno",objE.Alu_ApePaterno);
        }
```

Mi Capa Negocio :

```
public static DataTable Buscar_Alumno(Cls_E_Alumno objE)
        {
            return Cls_D_Alumno.Buscar_Alumno(objE);
        }
```

Mi capa Presentacion Codebing :

> ```
>    private void txtBuscar_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>           {
>               objE.Alu_ApePaterno = txtBuscar.Text;
> ```

```
        Buscar_Alumno(objE.Alu_ApePaterno);
    }
    public void Buscar_Alumno(string paterno)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = Cls_N_Alumno.Buscar_Alumno(objE);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dtListar_Alumno.Rows.Clear();
            dtListar_Alumno.RowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dtListar_Alumno[1, i].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
                dtListar_Alumno[2, i].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
                dtListar_Alumno[3, i].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pierro. Me alegra mucho que te estás aprovechando de la ayuda brindada en este sitio, pero noto que todavia te cuesta exponer tus preguntas de forma clara. Por ejemplo, mencionas que recibes un error, pero no das ningún detalle en cuanto a este, por citar un ejemplo. Te recomiendo repasar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para ayudarte a mejorar la calidad de las preguntas y, por extensión, la calidad de las respuestas que recibes.

Comment: @sstan Muchas gracias y losiento modificare mi pregunta

Comment: @sstan ya lo modifique espero que ahora si me puedan ayudar. Disuclpen a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la capa de datos no veo que envíes el parámetro @apellidopaterno al Store procedure "Buscar_Alumno".

```
public static DataTable Buscar_Alumno(Cls_E_Alumno objE)
  {
      return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(conexion, "Buscar_Alumno");
  }
```

**EDIT:**

Si el Datagridview ya tiene data antes de realizar la búsqueda prueba con este código:

```
public void Buscar_Alumno(string paterno)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = Cls_N_Alumno.Buscar_Alumno(objE);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dtListar_Alumno.DataSource = null;
        dtListar_Alumno.Rows.Clear();
        dtListar_Alumno.RowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dtListar_Alumno[1, i].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
            dtListar_Alumno[2, i].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
            dtListar_Alumno[3, i].Value = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: disculpa si lo puse pero me sale el error mira la imagen que subi ayudame. porfavor

Comment: ¿Antes de que realices la búsqueda el datagridview ya tiene data cargada?

Comment: Si ya tiene data cargada ahorita tomo foto y lo edito la pregunta

Comment: ya lo edite como la foto si hay data yo en el texbox pongo la letra F y me arroja ese error

Comment: Edité la respuesta, prueba si te funciona.

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad creo que solo faltaba poner este codigo cierto :

dtListar_Alumno.DataSource = null;

me podrias recomendar donde podria aprender mas sobre c# si esta bien lo que estoy realizando con 3 capas yo en todo en que sea registrar alumno modificar lo realizo con datatable si me podrias recomendar un libro o pagina para poder aprender